# In App Purchases-iOS non consumable

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am adding In-App purchases to my app.As I am new to development I'm in big confusion.
If I implement in-app purchase how will user pay money means from which wallet?
And for this should I integrate any other payment gateway in my app? And how will the client get money after completion of purchase?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202023

Comment: @vaibby thanks for your response but it hasn't cleared my confusion.I found one thing that I can't integrate any third party payment gateway for in app purchases..But How will I get money if any user buy my purchase ?? Tanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my experience below are my comments on your Question/confusion:

**1. How will user pay money of InApp purchase ?**

While the user needs to purchase any digital things from `Apple` user needs valid iTunes Account with attached Credit/Debit card in that iTunes account.

So while user purchase any digital things like **iBook, Music, Paid App, IAP (in-app Purchase)** it will directly deduct from his/her Credit/Debit card.

If any app owner selling any other physical good or services he/she can use any 3rd party payment gateway or use the default Apple pay if supported in that country.

Links for 3rd party Payment Gateway :

- [Paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-iOS/)
- [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/)
- [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios)
  etc...

**2. How seller get payment of InApp ?**

As per `Apple` guideline App developer need to add his/her bank detail into iTunes Connect banking section ([here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ManagingContractsandBanking.html)) from where Apple get all detail and pay all payable amount of iBook, Paid App, InApp Purchase with deduction of **30% as commission on that purchases**.

The seller can connect a personal or business bank account.  Apple doesn't allow any 3rd parties such as Paypal.

Hope this info will help you to understand Apple Payment system.

Comment: For testing purpose I'm using one itunes account.After that can I use client itunes account ?

Comment: For what purpose you are using itune account ? for Purchase testing or for adding InAPP product ?

Comment: First I need to add in-app purchase then have to test it.After this when submitting to appstore need to add client itunes account.

Comment: No First you need to add InApp purchase into client account and test it with Test user account and than submit it with app submit option.

Comment: @CodeCahnger Which certificate shall I use for In-App purchase?Development or Distribution ?